# executing check_nrpe from iCinga2

Tags: monitoring, nagios, nrpe, icinga

I am trying to execute nrpe plugin from my iCinga server like this

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H <host> -c \
'nrpe_check_traffic_status' -a '2' '3'  -p <port>
```

I have made some print in plugin this is the result

```
>>opt>> -w  >> arg 2
>>opt>> -c  >> arg -p                   ### THIS LINE IS ERROR ###
Threshold values should be numerical
```

It is not executed properly, It sends `-p` as second argument instead of `3` to remote `nrpe`

But same working when I give like this

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H <host> -c \
'nrpe_check_traffic_status' -p <port>-a '2' '3'
```

Result

```
>>opt>> -w  >> arg 2
>>opt>> -c  >> arg 3
TRAFFIC STATUS OK;
```

Did anyone faced this issue? Is there any solution for this?
Or is there any way to change this argument position in iCinga2 configuration?

Note: I have tried changing argument parameter up/down in `commands.conf` file, no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way to configure arguments position while executing from icinga,

Here is more info: [iCinga_Doc](http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/object-types#objecttype-checkcommand)

```
arguments = {
  "-X" = {
    value = "$x_val$"
    key = "-Xnew"       /* optional, set a new key identifier */
    description = "My plugin requires this argument for doing X."
    required = false    /* optional, no error if not set */
    skip_key = false    /* always use "-X <value>" */
    set_if = "$have_x$" /* only set if variable defined and resolves to a numeric value. String values are not supported */
    order = -1          /* first position */
    repeat_key = true   /* if `value` is an array, repeat the key as parameter: ... 'key' 'value[0]' 'key' 'value[1]' 'key' 'value[2]' ... */
  }
  "-Y" = {
    value = "$y_val$"
    description = "My plugin requires this argument for doing Y."
    required = false    /* optional, no error if not set */
    skip_key = true     /* don't prefix "-Y" only use "<value>" */
    set_if = "$have_y$" /* only set if variable defined and resolves to a numeric value. String values are not supported */
    order = 0           /* second position */
    repeat_key = false  /* if `value` is an array, do not repeat the key as parameter: ... 'key' 'value[0]' 'value[1]' 'value[2]' ... */
  }
}
```

Added `order` and `repeat_key=false` to my `command.conf` file. This solve my problem!!